# Cybersource creating customer payment instrument through Java SDK ; "message":"Invalid body values","details":[{"name":"type","location":"card"}]}

Tags: cybersource

refer to the sample code of cybersource I tried the same thing this is my card object

```
        card.expirationMonth(card.getExpirationMonth());
        card.expirationYear(card.getExpirationYear());
        card.type(cardDTO.getCardType());
        requestObj.card(card);
```

My flow to create customerpaymentId is ==> generate instrumentId ==> generate paymentInstrumentID ==> attached it to customerPaymentIdentifier API

Getting this error while calling customerPaymentIdentifier API

{"errors":[{"type":"invalidFields","message":"Invalid body values","details":[{"name":"type","location":"card"}]}]}

Also wanted to know can pass card details in encrypted and save those card details is it possible?
thanks in advance

Comment: card.expirationMonth("12");
  card.expirationYear("2031");
  card.type("001");
  requestObj.card(card);

Comment: Also  tried with this still the same error

Comment: {"errors":[{"type":"invalidFields","message":"Invalid body values","details":[{"name":"type","location":"card"}]}]}  is been resolved

Comment: Do you mind sharing the solution? I'm running into the same issue. Thanks